# How to add an object to an arraylist in a method

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to write a method that adds a Phone to an `ArrayList`.

Phone class:

```
public class Phone {
    private int id;
    private String brand;
    private String model;
    private int cameraResolution;
        
    public Phone(int id, String brand, String model, int cameraResolution) {
        this.id=id;
        this.brand=brand;
        this.model=model;
        this.cameraResolution= cameraResolution;
    }
    
    public void showDetails() {
        System.out.println("id "+ this.id);
        System.out.println("Marka to "+ this.brand);
        System.out.println("Model to "+ this.model);
        System.out.println("Rozdzielczosc aparatu to " + this.cameraResolution);            
    }
        
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Brand: " + this.brand + ", Model: " + this.model + ", Camera Resolution: " + this.cameraResolution + ", Id: " + this.id;
    }
}
```

Shop class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Shop {

    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Phone> phones;
    private ArrayList<Tv> tvs;
    
    public Shop(String name, ArrayList<Phone> phones, ArrayList<Tv> tvs ) {
        this.name=name;
        this.phones=phones;
        this.tvs=tvs;
    }
    
    public ArrayList<Phone> addNewPhone(Phone newPhone) {
        return phones.add(this.newPhone); // this doesnt work
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Phone galaxy= new Phone(1, "Samsung","galaxy",12);
        Phone lumia= new Phone(2, "Nokia","lumia",13);
        Phone pixel= new Phone(3, "Google","pixel",14);

    
        Phone[] phones = new Phone[3];  
        phones[0]= galaxy;
        phones[1]= lumia;
        phones[2]= pixel;
    
        for (Phone phone: phones) {
            phone.showDetails();
        }
    
        System.out.println(lumia.toString());
    
        Client client1= new Client(1, "Jan", "Kowalski", null);
        Client client2= new Client(1, "Magda", "Nowak", null);
    }

}
```

I know that I need to return an `ArrayList<Phone>` and I need to receive a type of `Phone` in this method, then it should return list of new phones, but I don't know why it's not working.

Eclipse shows this error : `newPhone cannot be resolved or is not a filed`.

Comment: `return phones.add(this.newPhone); // this doesnt work` 1) no `this` 2) why should the method return the whole `ArrayList`?

Comment: i deleted "this" and it didnt work; the method should return arraylist with 1 phone, or is there any other option?

Comment: Ok, but `add` returns a boolean, so if you *really* want to return the `ArrayList` (instead of having a getter for that field, for example) you'll have to do it in two steps, so `phones.add(newPhone); return phones;`

Comment: i thought that add is a arraylist method that simply adds the object to an arraylist; it worked, thank u for explanation!

Comment: It does exactly that, but it returns a boolean (always `true`), not the whole list. When learning to use a method you don't know don't assume how it works. Always read [its documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(E))

Comment: Can you tell me how i can actually use this function? i tried 

ArrayList<Phone> p1 = new ArrayList<Phone>(); 
p1.addNewPhone(galaxy);

in Main class but it didnt work

Comment: Most likely `ArrayList<Phone> p1 = new ArrayList<Phone>(); Shop s = new Shop("whatever name", p1, new ArrayList<Tv>); p1 = s.addNewPhone(galaxy);` But then again, the whole design here is weird and makes the code uselessly convoluted. It makes no sense here to pass an `ArrayList` to the constructor and `Shop` should have a `getPhones()` method that simply returns `phones`.

Comment: hey, thank u for help; i have  written task with following steps and i have to do it step by step for learning purpose;

Answer (score 0):

You have to problems in your method *addNewPhone*:

Probably do not want to add the field `newPhones` of the class `Shop` (because you don't have that field) but the method parameter of that name.

And none of the `ArrayList.add` overloads returns the list itself. As I don't see a single call of the *addNewPhone* method I can't really judge it, but I would think twice if you really need to return that list there

I would write it like this:

```java
public addNewPhone(Phone newPhone) {
    phones.add(newPhone);
}
```

If you need to return the `phones` list, I would always only use `List<Phone>` and never `ArrayList`, and probably also return `Collections.unmodifiableList(phones)`

Comment: how Can i actually add an phone to this arraylist using this method?
i tried:

Comment: ArrayList<Phone> p1 = new ArrayList<Phone>();
 p1.addNewPhone(galaxy);
in Shop and Main class but it didnt work

Comment: Please add some usage of the `Shop` class in your code (question) first, otherwise the `addNewPhone` method is useless.